# USB data detection

Tags: usb, usb-device

I am new to USB communication. I am studying the USB communication and protocol. I have always wondered about how USB devices actually communicate.
I have a microcontroller with USB peripheral. I am using this as device  and PC as host for USB communication.
Like, UART, the data(8 bits) are transmitted with start, stop and optional parity bit. But at they are excluded from the hardware of UART peripheral and we get ony 8 bit data. 
Similarly, how the data is transmitted or recieved in USB communication?
Alo, if i want to implement MODBUS protocol with USB communication can it be possible? Or the USB protocol is mandatory to use with USB communication.

Comment: I think you need to read the USB documentation a bit more. The specifications will spell out both the physical layer (PHY) requirements and the encoding+protocol for the half-duplex USB 1/1.1/2.0 standards.

Comment: Thanks for response. Can u suggest any book or documentation for same?

Comment: Why not start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB and http://www.usb.org/ ? They're the most immediate sources on the topic and can *easily* be found by doing some searching on the web.

Comment: This really is not a good type of question for this forum because there is no way to answer all your questions. You need to read up on USB. Start with these good web pages: http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb1.shtml and http://janaxelson.com/usb.htm

Comment: @Nama, please see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask Also see: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic The idea is that questions that can be learned by oneself are better learned by doing research (on the internet) There are plenty of resources available and us explaining them to you won't be useful. Plus answers can only be a few pages, explaining usb would be much more than a few pages.

Answer (score 2):

"USB" actually defines SEVERAL of the lower levels of the "OSI 7 Layer Model". Physical, electrical, logical, etc.

> if i want to implement MODBUS protocol with USB communication can it be possible?

Your question doesn't make sense as it stands. USB and Modbus each have their own DIFFERENT specs for physical, electrical, logical, etc. communication standards.  Certainly, you could translate and make an adapter or interface between Modbus and USB. In fact there appear to be commercial products billed as Modbus to USB adapters.

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus

Ref: http://www.schneider-electric.com/download/uk/en/details/643793054-TSXCUSBMBP-USB-Modbus-Plus-Communications-Adapter-Instruction-Sheet/